# AWS ALB Target Group shows unhealthy instances in a custom VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, health-check

I am trying to achieve the following network topology. I want the EC2 instances in private subnets to receive http traffic on port 80 from application load balancer.

[image]

For that

I have launched EC2 instances in both the private subnets each. Also, installed apache web server with index.html using the following user data script.

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd.x86_64
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
echo “Hello World from $(hostname -f)” > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Next, I created ALB in the public subnets. Also, registered EC2 instances with a Target Group while creating the ALB. But health checks for the registered EC2 instances always fail. Please find the image below.

[image]

I have double checked security groups for EC2 instances and ALB. Both looks fine to me. Could anyone please let me know what am I missing here ?

thanks

Comment: Do you have NAT gateway for the private instances to enable installing `httpd`?

Comment: Few things to check:
- what path are you using I the health checks?
- private subnet is allowed to receive traffic from public subnet?
- can load balancer security group access private ec2 security group?
- there is a routing provisioned / correct between private and public subnets?
- is ACL blocking traffic between subnets?

Comment: i hv added load balancer sg to security groups associated with EC2 instances. Also route tables are correctly configured. One rt for public and another for private subnets.

Comment: Can you provide exact details of your LB, Target groups, NAT gateway and RTs setup, security groups.

Comment: The first thing to check is that apache is actually running on the servers, and on port `80`. SSH into one of the servers and run a `curl http://localhost` to see if it is.